# Error : Dumping into Table Process : Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

While saving and creating a file, I am getting error as

> Error : Dumping  into Table Process : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFILE\BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_22\06\2021_ErrorFile.txt'

Below is my code for the same

```
public static void WriteMessageInfoInLogFile_Error(string data)
    {
        string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileDirectory"].ToString() + "BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace(":", "") + "_ErrorFile.txt";
        
        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(strPath, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.ASCII, 1024);
        sw.WriteLine("------ Erroneous Data not send to blockchain team ------------ ");
        sw.WriteLine("JSON String :" + data);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
        sw = null;
        fs = null;
    }
```

In `LogFileDirectory` the value is stored in App.Config file whose value is below

```
<add key="LogFileDirectory" value="C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFILE\"/>
```

Your kind assistance, will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Full ERROR

> 6/22/2021 2:29:56 AM : Error : Dumping  into Table Process : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFIE\BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_22\06\2021_ErrorFile.txt'.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updated error message, the file path begins with `C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFIE`. The "L" in FILE as part of MASTER_LOGFILE is missing. Perhaps you have a typo in the `LogFileDirectory` app setting?

Comment: No, I corrected that, still getting the same error... `2:44:11 AM : Error : Dumping  into Table Process : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFILE\BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_22\06\2021_ErrorFile.txt'`

Comment: The backslashes in the date component of the path seem error prone. Backslashes are used to separate different folder names in a path. Do you really have a folder named "BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_22", followed by a folder named "06"? Or do you have a file named "BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO_22\06\2021_ErrorFile.txt"?

Comment: I want to create that folder with `BLOCKCHAIN_DATA_INFO` followed by current date with my code..

Comment: OK, my guess is that you want to create a new file in "C:\BLOCKCHAIN\MASTER_LOGFILE", a folder that does exist. But you are inadvertently trying to create a file in a folder that doesn't exist. I think you should change your date format string to something like "dd_MM_yyyy". Underscores are valid as part of a file name, slashes are not since they are path separators.

Comment: that error is resolved, just one thing,, I want to give this format but its not working...`Tobj.RFCDates = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.RFCDATE, "dd-mm-yyyy");`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what ObjIp.RFCDATE is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234044/discussion-between-hud-and-jahan-afshari).

Comment: `ObjIp.RFCDATE` is string

Comment: Thanks Jahan, sorry for delay in accepting the answer